# Input field is always one value behind what Ive typed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, use-state

I am trying to build a date input for the first time. I have the task of making sure the input displays a leading 0 if the month or day are set to a single digit. The issue Im having is when a value is entered it doesnt make it to the next handler until the next time i type into a field. I believe this is because Im passing the value through the state. But im not sure how to have the state readily available to send right after the user types in the field:

State:

```
  const [date, setDate] = useState({ day: "", month: "", year: "" });
```

My date input consist of three separate inputs for mon/day/year ill only show month here:

```
<div className="nh-date">
          <Input
            onChange={dateChange("month")}
            value={date.month}
            className={`nh-mon ${!!error && "error"}`}
            name="month"
            id="mon"
            maxLength={2}
            type="number"
            selectTextOnFocus={true}
          />
          <span className="sep">/</span>
```

UseEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!!effectiveDate) {
      const effectiveMoment = !!effectiveDate ? moment.parseZone(effectiveDate) : {};
      setCalendarDate(effectiveMoment);
    }

    if (!!startDate) {
      const [month, day, year] = startDate.split("/");
      let shortYear = year.slice(-2);
      setDate({ ...date, day: day, month: month, year: shortYear });

      const newDate = `${month}/${day}/${year}`;
      if (moment(newDate).isValid()) {
        debounceCallback(handleDateInputChange, newDate);
        setError(false);
      } else {
        setError(true);
      }
    }
  }, [startDate, effectiveDate]);
```

My onChange handler looks like this:

```
     const dateChange = (field: string) => (e: any) => {
        // format to fit
        let value = e.target.value;
        let d = { day: "", month: "", year: "" };
        if (value.length < 2) {
          value = "0" + value;
        } else {
          //remove extra leading 0's
          value = value.slice(-2);
        }
    
        setDate({ ...date, [field]: value });
        const newDate = `${date.month}/${date.day}/20${date.year}`;
        setStartDate(newDate);
      };
```

Once I type into the field `debounceCallback(handleDateChange, newDate);` receives the `newDate` but not as it is currently shown it sends the initial or previous value. I still struggle with handling input in the state im not sure how to work around this any advice would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Change you `setDate` call to `setDate((prevState) => {return {...prevState, [field]: value }});`

Comment: @VitaliyRayets thanks for the response! Im not sure this works for setting the state. Could you explain what youre trying to do with this line?

Comment: setDate is asyncronous, you must call `debounceCallback` with new data in useEffect

Comment: I understand. Ive updated my code to show what my useEffect looks like. You can see Ive added the debounce inside the useEffect like you suggested. But still seeing the same issue

Comment: I wrote code snippet for you https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-bird-8qn07

Comment: You rewrite code with the same mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in useEffect your date is updated and you call callback with new date

```
const dateChange = (field: string) => (e: any) => {
    // format to fit
    let value = e.target.value;
    let d = { day: "", month: "", year: "" };
    if (value.length < 2) {
      value = "0" + value;
    } else {
        //remove extra leading 0's
      value = value - 0;
    }

    setDate((prevState) => {
        return { ...prevState, [field]: value };
    });
}

useEffect(() => {
  const newDate = `${date.month}/${date.day}/${date.year}`;
  if (moment(newDate).isValid()) {
    debounceCallback(handleDateChange, newDate);
    setError(false);
  } else {
    setError(true);
  }
}, [date, //rest dependencies]);
```

Comment: Ive been trying to understand your solution. I dont think this fixes the issue but it seems to cause another issue of overload by setting the state to trigger the useEffect.

Comment: Your problem in this code `setDate({ ...date, [field]: value }); ....`. Нou wrote it in a synchronous style, but work it asynhronous. You want to call `debounceCallback` with new date, but date isn't updated yet. In `useEffect` with depend `[date]` date will update already. That's why you must call `debounceCallback` in `useEffect`

Comment: I wrote code snippet for you https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-bird-8qn07

Comment: Thanks! That helped me fix the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Calling setState() in React is asynchronous, for various reasons (mainly performance). Under the covers React will batch multiple calls to setState() into a single state mutation, and then re-render the component a single time, rather than re-rendering for every state change.

```
I think you get previous value for Month 
setDate({ ...date, [field]: value }); not immediately update the state.

const dateChange = (field: string) => (e: any) => {
    // format to fit
    let value = e.target.value;
    let d = { day: "", month: "", year: "" };
    if (value.length < 2) {
      value = "0" + value;
    } else {
        //remove extra leading 0's
      value = value - 0;
    }

    setDate({ ...date, [field]: value });

    const newDate = `${value}/${date.day}/${date.year}`;
   
    if (moment(newDate).isValid()) {
      debounceCallback(handleDateChange, newDate);
      setError(false);
    } else {
      setError(true);
    }
  };
```

Comment: thanks for the response! I see what youre doing there with setting the month with the value. But that only works to fix the issue of the value of Month updating in readily. However I cant use value for all three fields so Im still having the same issue. Any thoughts?